# Pass data into a Polymer element without using polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, element

I am making the switch from the angular world over to polymer. I am doing this so I can create reusable components that are not dependent on large framework like angular.

I am wondering how I would pass data into an element with vanilla javascript or something like handlebars?

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="basic-nav/basic-nav.html">

  </head>
  <body>
    <basic-nav tabs='[{"key": "A","label": "sweet"},{"key": "B","label": "nice"}]' tab='A'></basic-nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Right now I have to hardcode a json string into the polymer element and it works. But I would like something like jquery or handlebars to dynamically add data to the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple. 
You can add id to the element / find this element is other way.

```
 document.getElementById('basicNavId').tabs=['some Array'];
```

Comment: Awesome, that did it =)

Comment: Even though this works the first time , yet when you update the data , from another call and run this step again , the new data does not show up .

So on the array property - i have used - 
observer: 'messagesChanged'

and this function gets called only once - for the first assignment and never again . I must be missing something .

Comment: can  you  post your code? (only the relevant part) or open new question with the code and give me a link?

Comment: I have created a question -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759735/updating-polymer-component-with-data-from-outside-the-component