# Updating Polymer Component with data from outside the component

Tags: socket.io, polymer

This should be a pretty normal task , and yet i am missing something .

I am trying to integrate Socket.io with Polymer [ using the chat application ] - Deciding to change the MessageList and the individual messageItem as Polymer components . 
  SocketIo exposes a customEvent to be thrown from server , which sends the message as data , which then is being assigned to a property on the custom element .

This is the MessageList element .

```
<link rel="import" href="/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="message.html">

<dom-module id='message-list'>
<template>

    <style>

    </style>

    <ul id="messages">
        <template is='dom-repeat' items="{{messageList}}" is="auto-binding">
            <li>
                <message-item message = "{{item}}"></message-item>
            </li>
        </template>
    </ul>

</template>
<script>
    var messageListElement = Polymer({
        is : 'message-list',
        properties : {
            messageList : {
                type : Array,
                observer: '_messageListChanged',
                reflect : true ,
                value : function() {
                    return [{'inputMessage' : 'Welcome to the Chat' , 
                    'nickName' : 'System' , 'msgTime' : new Date()}]
                }
                //, notify : true
            }
        },

        _messageListChanged: function(newValue , oldValue) {
            console.log("Data changed");
        },

        created : function() {
            console.log("messagelist created");
        },

        ready : function() {
            console.log("messagelist ready");
        },

        attributeChanged : function() {
            console.log("messagelist attributeChanged");
        }
    });
</script>
```

On the index.html Page -

```
var self = this;
socket.on('chatMessage' , function(msg) {
        self.messages.push(msg);
        console.log(self.messages);

        document.querySelector('message-list').messageList = self.messages;

    });
```

With all of this.. Anytime a client sends a message , the self.messages - posts the total set of messages , but the "_messageListChanged" of the custom elements gets called only the first time .

There are similar questions - [Updating a polymer element property with data from API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937345/updating-a-polymer-element-property-with-data-from-api-call)

However assigning the data , works only for the first time .
 Also i would like to be able to do it without using ajax-iron and stuff .

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using the [Polymer API for array mutations](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#array-mutation) (as Alon has pointed out in his answer), you need to install an observer for [array mutations](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#array-observation). The observer you have now will only fire when you assign a new array instance, but not when you add or remove elements from your array.

```
    properties : {
        messageList : {
             type : Array,
             value : function() {
                return [{'inputMessage' : 'Welcome to the Chat' , 
                'nickName' : 'System' , 'msgTime' : new Date()}]
            }
        }
    },
    observers: [
        '_messageListChanged(messageList.splices)'
    ],
```

Note that this kind of observer takes a single argument, a change record.

> Your observer method should accept a single argument. When your observer method is called, it receives a change record of the mutations that occurred on the array.

Comment: is he do splice on the array. it is not required to set this kind of observer, and how he wrote the observer is ok. But it also good.

Comment: @Alon You are right. However, as tony19 pointed out, splicing is not that efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use push. polymer has his own push function.The regular push does not trigger the observers, and all the change events.

```
this.push('array',value)
```

But for you, you can solve it like this:

```
var self = this;
socket.on('chatMessage' , function(msg) {
    self.messages.push(msg);


    document.querySelector('message-list').messageList = self.messages.slice();

});
```

The slice will create new array. And it will trigger all the change in the array.

Comment: Using `self.messages.slice()` on every chat message is highly inefficient and could be cost prohibitive for lengthy conversations.

Comment: this is true only for very very long arrays,try and see the time it takes to slice array with 1000 objects, if he want I  wrote the solution using the push of polymer...

Comment: What i went with is , exposing another function on the element ( is called from the JS ) , takes the new message and pushes it on to the messageList , using the mutation method that you have mentioned . So it does work now .

Answer (score -1):

please try adding `reflectToAttribute:true` to your messageList property.

if you still don't get it solved try to so this

```
self.myimmutedArray JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(self.messages))
```

before  `document.querySelector('message-list').messageList = self.myimmutedArray;`

reason could be the javascript array push or slice will not refelect in polymer's dirty checking

if you use below code in the a polymer component. you must follow polymer's array changes like

```
this.push('messages', {title:'hey'});

var self = this;
socket.on('chatMessage' , function(msg) {
        self.messages.push(msg);
        console.log(self.messages);

        document.querySelector('message-list').messageList = self.messages;

    });
```